# Blender 2.9 rx480 crashing

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I try to render this blender scene my pc screen blink black and after I get this message

[image]

Then blender is just white and not responding I need to kill it and try again with no success's

Here are some debug logs :

https://pastebin.com/K26TQreP

https://pastebin.com/hgRhmr1C

The blend file :

https://gofile.io/d/DkHbzm

More info :

- My rx480 have 8gb of vram
- My pc have 16gb of ram
- My cpu is a ryzen 5 1600

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133054/display-driver-stopped-working

Comment: didn't help, I don't know what to do.