# Computer crashes few minutes after I go into material preview mode [Eevee]

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Whenever I got into material preview or eevee viewport render, it all works fine for a few minutes and then my computer crashes. Screen flashes and goes black and everything freezes until I reboot. Blender crashes usually right before the screen dies. I have tried installing new and old drivers, cleaning my graphics card, updating windows. Nothing has helped. This is not scene specific, this happens in every scene, even scenes with not much going on.

I am using Blender 2.93, GT 730 GDDR3, Core i5-3470, Windows 10 Pro, 8 GB RAM. GT 730 Driver version: 23.21.13.9135.

I was using AMD Firepro v3900 previously, and a similar issue happened back then too, but it would take longer to crash. I am assuming this is a GPU issue, but I can't afford to get a better new one at the moment. I hope I can find some solutions to this, I can't work on my scenes as it keeps crashing.

I checked Event viewer and it said: "A TDR has been detected The application must close" on events for NVIDIA OPENGL DRIVER. TO resolve this I found a software to disabled TDR. And it did nothing, things still crash. But it doesn't report as a TDR issue on event viewer. Since this had no impact, Ill enable TDR back.

**Solved**
The issue was with the PSU. After tons of searching I found that was the issue, the GPU was crashing since it wasn't getting enough volts. The old PSU was not working to its full power. I have replaced it, and its working great now.

P.s. I did try many solutions regarding TDR values, they did not help this case.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133054/display-driver-stopped-working

Comment: HI Amber welcome to BSE Please use answer section below for answerr.